# Click in a React dropdown with SeleniumBase

Tags: javascript, selenium, seleniumbase

I have a webpage written in React using the Ant Design framework.
I am trying to test a dropdown with SeleniumBase (but also open to solutions with Selenium Webdriver)

The function can be found here: https://ant.design/components/select/

Called: Select with the search field

When you click the field there is a drop-down showing three options:

```
Jack  
Lucy  
Tom
```

I have identified the XPath to it as `'//*[@id="rc_select_13"]'`
I am trying to click and select one of the options, but even clicking on it seems impossible

```
from seleniumbase import BaseCase


class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_ant_dropdown(self):
        url = "https://ant.design/components/select/"
        self.open(url)
        self.assert_title("Select - Ant Design")
        self.click_xpath('//*[@id="rc_select_13"]')
```

The above code fails with `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException`

If I during the test manually help by clicking on the dropdown, the test exists with success.
I figured I need to click on it first to get a proper drop-down to select an option in afterward with the function `self.select_option_by_text()`

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happened was that the element had opacity set to zero. In SeleniumBase it will not click on anything that it thinks is invisible.

Some workarounds can be found here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/612